# Problema con vectores (index out of bounds) y con Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola hace varios días que llevo atorado en este problema. He revisado el programa de principio a fin varias veces y no encuentro el error. Eclipse arroja un "index -1 out of bounds" y adedmás aparecen dos JLabels que se superponen (cuando no deberían) .   La idea es simular un campeonato entero de fútbol. Necesito que el programa me muestre aleatoriamente qué equipo juega contra cuál, y a su vez, que cada véz que aprete el botón "jugar", cambien los adversarios para cada equipo, teniendo en cuenta que no puden volver a jugar contra los que ya jugaron antes. Para eso implementé dos vectores:  uno que agrupa a todos los equipos, y otro vector interno de cada equipo en el que entran los clubes con los que ya se ha jugado.  Les dejo el código:

NOTA1: El error surge de manera bastante aleatoria. El programa en un principio carga bien y luego empiza a tirar errores cuando presiono "jugar" una cantidad aleatoria de veces (Es decir, a veces tira el error la tercera vez que presiono, otras veces la quinta, etc) Y en ese momento no solo ocurre un problema en la consola sino que se superponen las etiquetas con los nombres de los equipos (ver foto)

NOTA2 2: Según Eclipse el error se da en el bucle WHILE que está dentro del método Fixture(). "Index -1 out of bounds". Yo ya sé que esto significa que el bucle está fallando e intentando mirar un objeto en la posición "-1" del vector (que obviamente no existe). Lo que no entiendo es por que sucede esto ya que en la lógica que pensé, el bucle debería cortarse mucho antes de llegar a -1.  Tampoco entiendo la superposición de etiquetas.

dejo el link de la imagen con la superposicion de etiquetas (no me deja subirla al post no se por que)  https://ibb.co/Jmh8vQg

````
package Pruebass;
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PcFutbol extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static int fecha = 1;   
    private JLabel proxpartido,posiciones,resultados,proxpartidoa;
    Equipo fechalista[] = new Equipo [10];
    int cargador = 0;
    int medidab = 80;
   JButton boton1;

   Equipo[] equipos = { new Equipo("independiente"), new Equipo("SanLorenzo"), new Equipo("lanus"), new Equipo("boca"),
            new Equipo("river"), new Equipo("racing"), new Equipo("banfield"), new Equipo("platense"),
            new Equipo("Newells"), new Equipo("central") };

   public PcFutbol() {
        setLayout(null);

        boton1=new JButton("Jugar");
        boton1.setBounds(300,250,100,30);
        add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);
        fixture();
      //  mostrarResultado();
      // ordenarTabla();
    }

    class Equipo {
        String nombre;
        Equipo[] partidosjugados = new Equipo[9];
        boolean tienepartido = false; // ESTE BOOLEAN sirve para que el método que recorre el vector para encontrar rival detecte si un equipo ya fue seleccionado para jugar esa fecha o no. 
        int comojugó;
        JLabel resultado = new JLabel("-");
        JLabel puntosb = new JLabel("-");
        JLabel nombres = new JLabel(nombre);
        JLabel nombresb = new JLabel(nombre + "  -  ");

        public Equipo(String a) {
            puntos = 0;
            calidad = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);

            nombre = a;
        nombres.setText(nombre);

        }

        public String toString(int a) {

            if (a == 1) {

                return nombre ;

            }
            else {
             String puntox = String.valueOf(puntos);
             return puntox;
            }

                    }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==boton1) {

        //  competir();
            resetearDatos();
            fecha++;
            fixture();
        //    ordenarTabla();          
        }
    }
    public void fixture() {

        int selecrival = 0;

        for (int q = 0; q < 9; q++) {

            if (equipos[q].tienepartido == true) {
                continue;
            }

            selecrival = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (9 - 1) + 1); 

            while (equipos[q] == equipos[selecrival]) {

                selecrival = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (9 - 1) + 1);
            }

            if (equipos[selecrival].tienepartido == true || yajugo(equipos[q], equipos[selecrival]) == true) {



                                int m = 9;
// EL BUCLE DE ABAJO ES EL QUE TIRA EL ERROR INDEX -1 OUT OF BOUNDS SEGÚN ECLIPSE
            while (equipos[q] == equipos[m] || equipos[m].tienepartido == true || yajugo(equipos[q], equipos[m]) == true) {

                        m--;                            
                }

                 fechaArmada(equipos[q], equipos[m]);           
                 continue;
            } 

            if (equipos[selecrival].tienepartido == false && yajugo(equipos[q], equipos[selecrival]) == false) {

                fechaArmada(equipos[q], equipos[selecrival]);

            }
        }
    }


    public void fechaArmada(Equipo a , Equipo b) {


        fechalista[cargador] = a; 
        fechalista[cargador+1] = b;
        cargador = cargador+2;

        a.partidosjugados[(fecha - 1)] = b;
        b.partidosjugados[(fecha - 1)] = a;

        a.tienepartido = true;
        b.tienepartido = true;

    a.nombresb.setText(a.nombre + "   -  ");    
    a.nombresb.setBounds(10, medidab, 300, 30);
    b.nombresb.setText(b.nombre);
    b.nombresb.setBounds(150,medidab,300,30);
    add(a.nombresb);
    add(b.nombresb);


     medidab = medidab + 15;
    }

    public boolean yajugo(Equipo a, Equipo b) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.partidosjugados.length; i++) {

            if (a.partidosjugados[i] == b) {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void resetearDatos() {

        for (int a = 0 ; a < equipos.length ; a++)  {

            equipos[a].tienepartido = false  ;

        }

        cargador = 0;
        medidab = 80;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PcFutbol uno = new PcFutbol();

        uno.setBounds(10,20,400,300);
        uno.setVisible(true);
        uno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
    ```





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxX7F.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás llegando a un punto donde m toma el valor 0, se ejecuta la condición del while con equipos[0] y dado que la condición se cumple, hace que m sea -1, luego al volver a evaluar la condición estás preguntando por equipos[-1], por lo que te manda error. Te sugiero que añadas a la condición del while: && m > 0, o bien podrías añadir un if dentro del while con la misma expresión y que en caso de que no se cumpla haga un break.

```
while (equipos[q] == equipos[m] || equipos[m].tienepartido == true || yajugo(equipos[q], equipos[m]) == true) {
   if (m > 0) {
      m--;
   } else break;                  
}
```

Además, como consejo, si vas a evaluar que una expresión sea verdadera, no es necesario que coloques "expresion == true", con solo "expresion" basta.

Comment: holas. Como dije, no debería llegar a 0 nunca. La idea es que encuentre un equipo para rivalizar antes que eso pero por algún motivo no pasa. Eso es lo que no entiendo. Aún si agregara esa condición hay algo que está funcionando mal.

Comment: curiosamente ademas de todo agregué esa condicion y sigue tirando el mismo error. Ahora estoy mas desorientado jaja. gracias igual!.

Comment: @favio El código que propuso jonat es totalmente correcto. Cuando dices: *no debería llegar a 0 nunca.* Es una afirmación, sin embargo, en alguna ocasiones estamos tan seguro que la lógica del algoritmo está bien, pero esa **seguridad** es lo que te hace confiar que esté bien cuando en realidad no es así. ¿Quieres saber si **realmente** `m` nunca llegara a `0`? Pues aplicale una depuración manual, es decir, después del while añade un `print` para ver con que valor queda al final la variable `m`. Lo más probable es que sea un error lógico.

Comment: holas . Ya agregué la condición y me sigue tirando el mismo error. El while quedó así:
 ``` int m = 9;
   while (m > 0 && equipos[q] == equipos[m] || equipos[m].tienepartido  || yajugo(equipos[q], equipos[m])  ) {

      m--;       
    }  ```
Además lo que quise decir es que aún si M llegara a -1 (cosa que nunca negué) el problema es que no entiendo por que sucede ya que no debería. El while que recorre el vector está pensado para encontrar un rival disponible para equipos[q] y sin embargo por algún motivo que no veo, eso no pasa y el while se sigue ejecutando.

Comment: Entonces dado que la lógica de tu programa no funciona como esperas, lo recomendable es que hagas un debug colocando los breakpoints en las lineas donde consideres que el código no funciona correctamente, así podrás ver qué es lo que hace tu programa para que te salga el error.

Comment: @favio La condición que has propuesto está mal hecha. Cuando la condición `m > 0` no se cumpla, se cumplirá la condición `equipos[m].tienepartido` y ahí de nuevo dará la excepción. Debes usar paréntesis en cada condición (en este caso si).

Comment: @favio Por ejemplo, esta condición: `m > 0 && x == 2 || x == 1`, es diferente a: `(m > 0) && (x == 2 || x == 1)`. Te recomiendo usar exactamente el código que ha propuesto jonat. Por cierto, trata de etiquetar en los comentarios, de lo contrario no me llegara la notificación.